# If I want to make a project for image patent, what should I learn?

Tags: web3js, parity, genesis

I'm new to Ethereum. Such as title, I want to make a project for image patent. I think it's a PoA project. Now I am studying Parity. And I have tried some tutorial, too. I can run a private chain in Docker with Parity and make some simple transaction now. But I don't know what should I do next. Maybe I need to study about how to write an GenesisBlock，
or how to use Web3? 
I'm very confused now. Could you give me some advice or some tutorials? 
And I want to know which client is most suitable for my project? There are so many client, I don't know choose which one to start... :(
Thanks a lot!！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this course is really good https://www.udemy.com/ethereum-developer/learn/v4/overview . Unfortunately it's paid but atm it's only 10usd. *Disclamer: I'm not related to the guys who did it, I've just taken it some time ago*

In terms of what you need to get started, I can recommend:

1. Investigate some basics about how ethereum works (accounts, ether, gas, web3js). So you can have an idea about how do you want to model your solution. (For example, a super naive implementation could be a smart contract to store a set of (owner address, image hash and timestamp) and a method to allow a user to check if it exists or not and who's the owner.
2. Setup a test node using Parity or Geth (they are both great clients, you can try Geth as it has a great javascript console to play).
3. Download [Mist wallet](https://github.com/ethereum/mist) and try to play with a test chain.
4. Learn about [solidity](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) which is the most common language used to write Smart Contracts
5. Check out [Truffle](https://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It's a great tool that will allow you to write and test the smarts contracts you create

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow! That's so detailed! It helps me a lot! I'm studying about Truffle now. Hope I can know more about contracts. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are trying to put a proof that certain image was created by someone at a certain time by putting it on a Blockchain?

If that's the case, then you should start with how to hash images (Backend of choice) and design a Solidity Smart Contract to put the hash in a Blockchain.

PoA and Parity are on the network type layer and you can worry about that later. Start with testrpc and Remix IDE. Then, you can try interacting with your contracts via web3.js

testrpc: https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc 
Remix IDE: https://github.com/ethereum/remix 
Web3: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js